# USING TEXTJOIN AND UNIQUE OVER NON-CONTINUOUS CELLS

Tags: google-sheets, unique, textjoin

OK, relatively simple, but frustrating for me.  I think my issue isn't with the TEXTJOIN, but in defining a non-continuous series of cells for the UNIQUE function.

In cell A1, I am using this formula:
=TEXTJOIN("
",UNIQUE(B1,E1,H1,K1,N1))

NOTE: I am trying to do this for a row, and not the entire column that the data is in.

My thought was that it would join only unique values from that series, separated by a hard return.

However, I get an error.
[Image of a Google Sheet error with my formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2lSl.png)

So, looking for a way to look at a non-continuous series of cells in a row, pull out only unique values, and TEXTJOIN them together with a hard return (new line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula should be

```
=textjoin(" ",true,unique({B1;E1;H1;K1;N1}))
```

encapsulate the cells by {}

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=JOIN(" "; UNIQUE({B1;E1;H1;K1;N1})
```

or:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE({B1;E1;H1;K1;N1}),,9^9)
```